# MySQL block selecting/reading a specific row

Tags: mysql

I am developing a call center IVR system with heavy traffic. I want to give each caller a random FREE representative to chat with.

What i do now is:

```
SELECT admin FROM admins WHERE live = 1 AND available = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

After i get the free representative, i update him to be unavailable as so:

```
UPDATE admins SET available = 0 WHERE admin = XXX
```

After testing this, i noticed than caller sometimes end up with the same representative at the same time if they call at almost the same time.

I have tried adding "FOR UPDATE" to the select query, but it's not really helping with locking the row for select.

Any idea how can this problem be approached?

Answer (score 1):

This is called a race condition.  One method is to lock the table, but that can slow things down.  Another idea is to do the update and fetch the id at the same time:

```
UPDATE admins 
    SET available = if(@id := admin, 0, 0)
    WHERE live = 1 AND available = 1
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 1;

SELECT @id;
```

This will return the `id` of the affected row.